# Proving a set is a function

Tags: functions, proof-verification, relations

Is the set $\theta = \{((x,y),(3y,2x,x+y)):x,y \in R \}$ a function? If so, what is the domain and range?

I know a set is a function if it is a relation and one input has exactly one output for all inputs but I’m confused with the notation. I know that $xRy$ since $(x,y) \in R \times R$ but $(3y, 2x, x+y)$ is tripping me up since that is a $3$-dimensional coordinate. Any help?

Comment: Your formula has two `(` and three `)` in it. Are you quoting it correctly?

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes I am sure it’s right

Comment: Then I'm afraid it's nonsense and you should ask whoever gave you the formula to correct it into something where the parentheses at least balance.

Comment: Well I just realized what you meant by your first comment I forgot a parenthesis right after the first bracket. I fixed that. It’s in my proof book. I’d post a pic but I don’t have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that function takes pairs of real numbers $(x,y)$ into $(3y,2x,x+y)$.
Thus, the domain of that function, $\theta$, is  $\mathbb R^2$ and the codomain is $\mathbb R^3$. The range of $\theta$ is given by
$$\{ (3y,2x,x+y):\, x,y\in \Bbb R \} \subset \Bbb R^3$$
As you can see, the function can be written using a more recognizable way instead of a set :
$$\begin{align} 
\theta : \Bbb R^2 &\to \Bbb R^3 \\
(x,y) &\mapsto (3y,2x,x+y)
\end{align}$$
or simply $\theta (x,y) = (3y,2x,x+y)$.

**Remark :** To prove that $\theta$ is a true function you have to use the definition, that is, if $(x_1,x_2)=(y_1,y_2)$ then $\theta (x_1,x_2)= \theta(y_1,y_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your function takes $(x,y)$ into $(3y,2x,x+y)$ thus the domain is $\mathbb {R^2}$ and the codomain is $\mathbb {R^3}$

It is well defined because if $$(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$$ then $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$ therefore,  $$(3y_1,2x_1,x_1+y_1)=   (3y_2,2x_2,x_2+y_2)$$

Your function is indeed a linear transformation which could be represented by a $3\times 2 $ matrix.